# Angular - how can i reflect component inputs

Tags: angular

I'm using storybook, every time that i create a new component i need to export file with the component bindings (public inputs/outputs).

There is any way that i can read those inputs dynamically from the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory).

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core'

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver){}
```

and then in your method

```
getInputs(){
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType); 
  // where componentType is the component you want to get inputs from
  console.log(factory.inputs) // gives you an array of inputs;
}
```

EDIT:

You also need to add the component that needs to be resolved in the [`entryComponents`](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components) of the module using the factory.

Comment: Though, this approach is also listing dependencies injected due to declaration in component's constructor. Is there a way to get only those inputs that have been declared accordingly by using decorator `@Input()`? - **UPDATE:** wait, my fault ... I was using created component instead of factory used to create it.